# Error message is showing only firsrt character in Flutter flush bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show the error string if the user has already signed up. For that I have ErrorGroup but it is acting a bit weird. The first print output is "response.data {phone_number: User with this phone number is already registered.}"
The second print output is "errorStringer U"

I want to show the whole sentence and not the first character. Why I am losing other characters here?

```
    case DioErrorType.RESPONSE:
      if (dioError.response.statusCode != null) {
        status = dioError.response.statusCode;
        print("response.data ${dioError.response.data}");
      }
      try {
        ErrorGroup er = ErrorGroup.fromJson(dioError.response.data, status);
        print("errorString ${er.errorString}");
        return er;
      } catch (err) {
        return ErrorGroup.fromJson({"detail": "server error"}, status);
      }
      break;
```

Comment: Can you check/ share the ErrorGroupModel particularly the toJson method.

Comment: json['phone_number'][0] some one put [0] and now it works correctly.